# rendering issue with Safari 6 or Bootstrap modal dialogs?

Tags: safari, twitter-bootstrap, safari6

The bootstrap Modal dialogs are rendering like this in Safari 6

[image]

Is this an issue with Safari or the Bootstrap framework?

Comment: Could you do this up in a JSFiddle or JSBin demo? I'm not seeing the same problem in Chrome, but I'm not sure that my example has parity with yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've not mentioned that what exactly is the rendering issue with safari I assume the blue outline you are talking about

So I guess safari is using it's default `outline` for your focused modal window

Use CSS

First simply try this :

```
.yourmodalcontainer {
   outline: 0px;
}
```

If still not succeeded try the following..

```
.yourmodalcontainer:focus {
   outline: 0px;
}
```

for your modal window..this should be than fixed..

Comment: Don't forget to read the text of the image. ;)  Also, FYI on the outline issue, that is considered a Bootstrap issue and it is slated be fixed in 2.1.2, which should be out next week.

Comment: thats easy to set `overflow-y: scroll;`

Comment: @merv Thank you :) good to know its going to be fixed ... I'll simply wait for their fix instead oh patching it myself. Thank you both for your feedback :)

Comment: PS. marking as answer because the supplied css does remove the border for now.

Comment: @Nippysaurus it is a correct way to remove it, and btw that's an outline and not a border, it does not take any space in the box model ;)